# How to make actions from notification?

Tags: apex, notification

Every time a new User logs into the org, they have to accept some policies regarding assigning assets to them etc. They should get a notification with the possibility to accept the agreement, which subsequently changes some field on the User object (isAccepted boolean or whatever). I was thinking of maybe creating a FeedItem from Apex but is there any way to connect it with a quick action, or a method, or whatever could do some actions with data after clicking a link?

Comment: Have you looked at Login Flows?

Comment: @DavidCheng How come I never thought of it! Thanks!